# How to plot long and short positions like the ones using the drawing tool, from pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to draw long and short positions like the ones on the image automatically using pinescript.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With [strategy.position_size](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size) you can create a rule with your colors
Something like that:

```
// tpLvl = Your Take Profit level
// slLvl = Your Stop Loss level
p_tpLvl      = plot(
  strategy.position_size != 0 ? tpLvl : na,
  title      = 'Take Profit',
  color      = strategy.position_size != 0 and 
               strategy.position_size == strategy.position_size[1] ?
               color.new(color.green, 0) : na,
  linewidth  = 1,
  style      = plot.style_linebr)
p_slLvl      = plot(
  strategy.position_size != 0 ? slLvl : na,
  title      = 'Stop Loss',
  color      = strategy.position_size != 0 and 
               strategy.position_size == strategy.position_size[1] ?
               color.new(color.red,   0) : na,
  linewidth  = 1,
  style      = plot.style_linebr)
p_entryLvl   = plot(
  strategy.position_size != 0 ? strategy.opentrades.entry_price : na,
  title      = 'Entry Price',
  color      = strategy.position_size != 0 and 
               strategy.position_size == strategy.position_size[1] ?
               color.new(color.white, 0) : na,
  linewidth  = 1,
  style      = plot.style_linebr)
fill(
  p_entryLvl, p_tpLvl,
  color      = strategy.position_size != 0 and 
               strategy.position_size == strategy.position_size[1] ?
               color.new(color.green, 80) : na,
  title      = 'Take Profit Area')
fill(
  p_entryLvl, p_slLvl,
  color      = strategy.position_size != 0 and 
               strategy.position_size == strategy.position_size[1] ?
               color.new(color.red,   80) : na,
  title      = 'Stop Loss Area')
```